# Three.js print name as text with dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, mathjax

Three.js 3d globe i need to print names with dots each dot has a name its currently taking image as dot this is the code

```
var loader2 = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader2.crossOrigin = null;
dotTexture = loader.load("/dotTexture.png");
```

I want here every dot with name (text) how it is doable ?

Below is the codepen link where im working on

https://codepen.io/Mamboleoo/pen/LLxjzq

Reference link:
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_pdb.html

Comment: yes a sort of i need to print name with each point here

Comment: https://codepen.io/Mamboleoo/pen/LLxjzq